# Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE. Ограничить количество файлов

Tags: java, android

В приложении реализован выбор нескольких файлов. Код:

```
public void performFileSearch() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

Нужно ограничить максимальное количество файлов, которое может выбрать пользователь. Например, не больше 5 файлов. Очень желательно при этом не использовать библиотеки, а оставить стандартный файловый менеджер телефона, если это вообще возможно. Подскажите, как такое реализовать? Если нельзя без библиотек, то какие есть более подходящие?